# Complex URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Might be that my question is asked by someone before and I failed to find the similar question.

I have used a rewrite engine to rewrite my url

from: `http://www.domain.com/index.php?main=web&sub=email&id=2`

to: `http://www.domain.com/web/email/2`

But now on `index.php` I want to let the user delete this record by telling `index.php` through a query string to delete the record having id 2 belongs to category main blabla and sub category blabla, the url looks like `http://www.domain.com/web/email/2?delete=true` that will be equal to `http://www.domain.com/index.php?main=web&sub=email&id=2&delete=true`

How should I write a rule for this type of url? Remember that I want to delete record in this way

Comment: Which engine are you using for rewrites?

Comment: I am using apache server

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify `QSA` flag for your `RewriteRule`

Read [more](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA).

Answer (score 1):

use QSA (Query String Append) at the end of the like [QSA]

Comment: Please add some explanation how to do it!